# How to plot a linear regression with datetimes on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, linear-regression

My DataFrame object looks like

```
            amount
date    
2014-01-06  1
2014-01-07  1
2014-01-08  4
2014-01-09  1
2014-01-14  1
```

I would like a sort of scatter plot with time along the x-axis, and amount on the y, with a line through the data to guide the viewer's eye. If I use the pandas plot `df.plot(style="o")` it's not quite right, because the line is not there. I would like something like the examples [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html).

Answer (score 26):

*note: this has a lot in common with Ian Thompson's answer but the approach is different enough to have it be a separate answer. I use the DataFrame format provided in the question and avoid changing the index.*

Seaborn and other libraries don't deal as well with datetime axes as you might like them to. Here's how I'd work around it:

### Start by adding a column of date ordinals

Seaborn will deal better with these than with dates. This is a handy trick for doing all kind of mathy things with dates and libraries that don't love dates.

```
from datetime import date

df['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())
```

[image: dataframe with ordinals]

### Make a plot with the ordinals on the date axis

```
ax = seaborn.regplot(
    data=df,
    x='date_ordinal',
    y='amount',
)
# Tighten up the axes for prettiness
ax.set_xlim(df['date_ordinal'].min() - 1, df['date_ordinal'].max() + 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, df['amount'].max() + 1)
```

### Replace the ordinal X-axis labels with nice, readable dates

```
ax.set_xlabel('date')
new_labels = [date.fromordinal(int(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

[image: plot with regression line]

ta-daa!

Comment: This is great! I'd just add that I had to use

`new_labels = [dt.date.fromordinal(int(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]`

as I had `import datetime as dt` at the top of my script. I guess this answer assumes the user has done `from datetime import date` already.

Comment: yeah, you need that date import; it's in the first code block. Skip steps at your own risk ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since Seaborn has trouble with dates, I'm going to create a work-around.
First, I'll make the Date column my index:

```
# Make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount' : [1,
                               1,
                               4,
                               1,
                               1]},
                  index = ['2014-01-06',
                           '2014-01-07',
                           '2014-01-08',
                           '2014-01-09',
                           '2014-01-14'])
```

Second, convert the index to pd.DatetimeIndex:

```
# Make index pd.DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

And replace the original with it:

```
# Make new index
idx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
```

Third, reindex with the new index (idx):

```
# Replace original index with idx
df = df.reindex(index = idx)
```

This will produce a new dataframe with NaN values for the dates you don't have data:

[image: df edit]

Fourth, since Seaborn doesn't play nice with dates and regression lines I'll create a row count column that we can use as our x-axis:

```
# Insert row count
df.insert(df.shape[1],
          'row_count',
          df.index.value_counts().sort_index().cumsum())
```

Fifth, we should now be able to plot a regression line using 'row_count' as our x variable and 'amount' as our y variable:

```
# Plot regression using Seaborn
fig = sns.regplot(data = df, x = 'row_count', y = 'amount')
```

Sixth, if you would like the dates to be along the x-axis instead of the row_count you can set the x-tick labels to the index:

```
# Change x-ticks to dates
labels = [item.get_text() for item in fig.get_xticklabels()]

# Set labels for 1:10 because labels has 11 elements (0 is the left edge, 11 is the right
# edge) but our data only has 9 elements
labels[1:10] = df.index.date

# Set x-tick labels
fig.set_xticklabels(labels)

# Rotate the labels so you can read them
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)

# Change x-axis title
plt.xlabel('date')

plt.show();
```

[image: plot edit 2]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

- The `datetime dtype` values must be converted to something like `ordinal`
- This can be done by calculating the model with [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) and then adding the regression line with  [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

  - `sns.lineplot(x=[x1_date, x2_date], y=[y1, y2], label='Linear Model', color='magenta')` also works.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `sklearn 0.24.2`**

```py
import yfinance as yf  # for data
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# download the data
data = yf.download('aapl', '2019-01-02', '2021-01-01')

# add an ordinal column because sklearn doesn't work with datetimes
data['ordinal'] = data.index.map(pd.Timestamp.toordinal)

# create the model
model = LinearRegression()

# extract x and y from dataframe data
x = data[['ordinal']]
y = data[['Adj Close']]

# fit the mode
model.fit(x, y)

# print the slope and intercept if desired
print('intercept:', model.intercept_[0])
print('slope:', model.coef_[0][0])

# select x1 and x2 and get the corresponding date from the index
x1 = data.ordinal.min()
x1_date = data[data.ordinal.eq(x1)].index[0]
x2 = data.ordinal.max()
x2_date = data[data.ordinal.eq(x2)].index[0]

# calculate y1, given x1
y1 = model.predict(np.array([[x1]]))[0][0]

print('y1:', y1)

# calculate y2, given x2
y2 = model.predict(np.array([[x2]]))[0][0]

print('y2:', y2)

[out]:
intercept: -90078.45713565295
slope: 0.12225139598567565
y1: 28.279040945126326
y2: 117.40030861868581
```

### Plot

```py
ax1 = data.plot(y='Adj Close', c='k', figsize=(15, 6), grid=True, legend=False)
ax1.plot([x1_date, x2_date], [y1, y2], label='Linear Model', c='magenta')
ax1.legend()
```

[image]