# Graph section of a row in Seaborn Scatter

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataframe that is column indexed by datetime and I want to scatterplot a section of each row indexed by the datetime in the column in Seaborn. I do not know how to do this and make it look readable.

I have tried using loc and iloc in the x and y axis for the scatter call but I have not been able to get it to plot.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'123': ['20.908', 8.743, 8.34, 2.4909],
                 '124': ["2", 2.34, 0, 4.1234],
                  '412': ["3", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '516': ["5", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '129': ["10", 20.123, 3.123123, 0]},

                 index=['2015-01-10', '2015-02-10', '2015-03-10', '2015-04-10'])

df2 = df.transpose()
```

df2 is the dataframe I want to graph although either could work.

The desired output is a scatterplot of each row where x is indexed by time and y is the row value.

Comment: What do you mean by 'graph a section of each row'? Also, why are some of your values strings and others floats?

Comment: I want to be able to say "graph 2015-02-10 to 2015-04-10". Its just a placeholder for the example that I do not want to graph that column. The top row was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of guesswork, but...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'123': [20.908, 8.743, 8.34, 2.4909],
                 '124': [2, 2.34, 0, 4.1234],
                  '412': [3, 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '516': [5, 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '129': [10, 20.123, 3.123123, 0]},

                 index=['2015-01-10', '2015-02-10', '2015-03-10', '2015-04-10'])

# Melt & set index as datetime
df = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index', var_name='col', value_name='value').set_index('index')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index))

# Select data to plot by slicing datetime index
df_plot = df.loc[(df.index > pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01')) 
              & (df.index < pd.Timestamp('2015-04-30'))]

# Plot
sns.scatterplot(data=df_plot,
                x=df_plot.index.to_native_types(),
                    # Use to_native_types to handle datetime index
                y='value',
                hue='col',
                palette=sns.color_palette("Set1", df_plot['col'].nunique()))
                    # Specify palette & number of colors to 
                    # handle values stored as strings 
                    # (seemingly a seaborn bug)
```

[image: Scatterplot]

Note that seaborn does not handle dates very well, and there are better ways of handling datetime axes than in this answer. See, *e.g.*, [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308729/can-i-plot-a-linear-regression-with-datetimes-on-the-x-axis-with-seaborn?rq=1).