# How to use pandas DataFrame or Series with seaborn compliantly?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, seaborn

I import this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/individual+household+electric+power+consumption) and select an interval with

```py
data_frame = pd.read_csv('household_power_consumption.txt', 
                 sep=';', 
                 parse_dates={'dt' : ['Date', 'Time']}, 
                 infer_datetime_format=True, 
                 low_memory=False, 
                 na_values=['nan','?'], 
                 index_col='dt')
df_08_09 = data_frame.truncate(before='2008-01-01', after='2010-01-01')
df_08_09.info()
```

to get

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1052641 entries, 2008-01-01 00:00:00 to 2010-01-01 00:00:00
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Global_active_power      1052641 non-null float64
Global_reactive_power    1052641 non-null float64
Voltage                  1052641 non-null float64
Global_intensity         1052641 non-null float64
Sub_metering_1           1052641 non-null float64
Sub_metering_2           1052641 non-null float64
Sub_metering_3           1052641 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(7)
memory usage: 64.2 MB
```

I just wanted to know how I can treat the *DatetimeIndex* `dt` as a data column as well to make use of `lmplot()` or `regplot()` as, for, e.g.:

```py
seaborn.regplot(x="dt", y="Global_active_power", data=df_08_09)
```

The `dt` is always making problems, because seaborn is not able to access it for some reason. I tried to access the *DatetimeIndex*, but i found no way to extract it and make it a data column, due to the fact that I'm not quite used to pandas.

I expect seaborn to find `dt` in the data, but it doesn't and throws an error accordingly. It's clear for me to see that, but idk how to treat this in an efficent python/pandas/seaborn fashion. So please help me out! :)

...An other question btw... I'm also wondering why `df_08_09.Global_active_power.values` is returning an `(n,)` shaped np.array and not `(n,1)`. I'm always forced to do `values = np.array([values]).transpose()` to recover `(n,1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround and convert the datetime-columns to an integer first and replace the axis-tick-labels of matplotlib with the datetime-values afterwards, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
from datetime import datetime


data_frame = pd.read_csv('household_power_consumption.txt', 
                 sep=';', 
                 parse_dates={'dt' : ['Date', 'Time']}, 
                 infer_datetime_format=True, 
                 low_memory=False, 
                 na_values=['nan','?']) 
                 #index_col='dt') No need for this, as we are not working with indexes
df_08_09 = data_frame.truncate(before='2008-01-01', after='2010-01-01')

# Convert to integers
df_08_09['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df_08_09['dt']).apply(lambda date: date.timestamp())

# Plotting as integers
ax = seaborn.regplot(data=df_08_09, x="date_ordinal", y="Global_active_power")

# Adjust axis
ax.set_xlim(df_08_09['date_ordinal'].min() - 1, df_08_09['date_ordinal'].max() + 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, df_08_09['Global_active_power'].max() + 1)

# Set x-axis-tick-labels to datetime
new_labels = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels, rotation = 45)
```

Reference: [This SO answer by waterproof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308729/can-i-plot-a-linear-regression-with-datetimes-on-the-x-axis-with-seaborn?rq=1)

Comment: The truncation doesn't work with your solution. I'm getting data lying after 2010-01-01. Therefore the indexing with `index_col='dt'` needs to be carried out so you end up with redundant data columns. Actually I thought there would be something more elegant, pointing to the index column, but as a "quick and dirty" solution acceptable