# _nanquantile_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, u8darts

I have a pandaas dataframe with about 6k rows, with a timestamp column which is hourly and a value which is a float.

I am using DARTS for prediction and plotting

```
import pandas as pd
from darts import TimeSeries
df = dfTienen_final.toPandas()
df_no_duplicates = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['belgium_time'])

series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df_no_duplicates, "belgium_time", "avg_value", freq="H")
# Determine the number of rows in the DataFrame
num_rows = len(series)

# Set aside a percentage of the rows for validation (e.g., 10%)
validation_percentage = 10  # Adjust as needed
num_validation_points = (validation_percentage * num_rows) // 100  # Calculate the number of validation points

# Set aside the calculated number of rows as a validation series
train, val = series[:-num_validation_points], series[-num_validation_points:]

from darts.models import ExponentialSmoothing

model = ExponentialSmoothing()
model.fit(train)
prediction = model.predict(len(val), num_samples=1000)
```

and then this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

series.plot()
prediction.plot(label="forecast", low_quantile=0.05, high_quantile=0.95)
plt.legend()
```

However I get this error in the plot

_nanquantile_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'

traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-3591413550716749>, line 4
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 series.plot()
----> 4 prediction.plot(label="forecast", low_quantile=0.05, high_quantile=0.95)
      5 plt.legend()

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-c1295c6b-8422-4d69-982b-173176ff6a3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/darts/timeseries.py:3820, in TimeSeries.plot(self, new_plot, central_quantile, low_quantile, high_quantile, default_formatting, label, max_nr_components, ax, *args, **kwargs)
   3818         central_series = comp.mean(dim=DIMS[2])
   3819     else:
-> 3820         central_series = comp.quantile(q=central_quantile, dim=DIMS[2])
   3821 else:
   3822     central_series = comp.mean(dim=DIMS[2])

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-c1295c6b-8422-4d69-982b-173176ff6a3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py:5123, in DataArray.quantile(self, q, dim, method, keep_attrs, skipna, interpolation)
   5015 def quantile(
   5016     self: T_DataArray,
   5017     q: ArrayLike,
   (...)
   5022     interpolation: QuantileMethods | None = None,
   5023 ) -> T_DataArray:
   5024     """Compute the qth quantile of the data along the specified dimension.
   5025 
   5026     Returns the qth quantiles(s) of the array elements.
   (...)
   5120        The American Statistician, 50(4), pp. 361-365, 1996
   5121     """
-> 5123     ds = self._to_temp_dataset().quantile(
   5124         q,
   5125         dim=dim,
   5126         keep_attrs=keep_attrs,
   5127         method=method,
   5128         skipna=skipna,
   5129         interpolation=interpolation,
   5130     )
   5131     return self._from_temp_dataset(ds)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-c1295c6b-8422-4d69-982b-173176ff6a3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py:8035, in Dataset.quantile(self, q, dim, method, numeric_only, keep_attrs, skipna, interpolation)
   8029     if name not in self.coords:
   8030         if (
   8031             not numeric_only
   8032             or np.issubdtype(var.dtype, np.number)
   8033             or var.dtype == np.bool_
   8034         ):
-> 8035             variables[name] = var.quantile(
   8036                 q,
   8037                 dim=reduce_dims,
   8038                 method=method,
   8039                 keep_attrs=keep_attrs,
   8040                 skipna=skipna,
   8041             )
   8043 else:
   8044     variables[name] = var

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-c1295c6b-8422-4d69-982b-173176ff6a3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py:2292, in Variable.quantile(self, q, dim, method, keep_attrs, skipna, interpolation)
   2288 axis = np.arange(-1, -1 * len(dim) - 1, -1)
   2290 kwargs = {"q": q, "axis": axis, "method": method}
-> 2292 result = apply_ufunc(
   2293     _wrapper,
   2294     self,
   2295     input_core_dims=[dim],
   2296     exclude_dims=set(dim),
   2297     output_core_dims=[["quantile"]],
   2298     output_dtypes=[np.float64],
   2299     dask_gufunc_kwargs=dict(output_sizes={"quantile": len(q)}),
   2300     dask="parallelized",
   2301     kwargs=kwargs,
   2302 )
   2304 # for backward compatibility
   2305 result = result.transpose("quantile", ...)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-c1295c6b-8422-4d69-982b-173176ff6a3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py:1207, in apply_ufunc(func, input_core_dims, output_core_dims, exclude_dims, vectorize, join, dataset_join, dataset_fill_value, keep_attrs, kwargs, dask, output_dtypes, output_sizes, meta, dask_gufunc_kwargs, *args)
   1205 # feed Variables directly through apply_variable_ufunc
   1206 elif any(isinstance(a, Variable) for a in args):
-> 1207     return variables_vfunc(*args)
   1208 else:
   1209     # feed anything else through apply_array_ufunc
   1210     return apply_array_ufunc(func, *args, dask=dask)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-c1295c6b-8422-4d69-982b-173176ff6a3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py:761, in apply_variable_ufunc(func, signature, exclude_dims, dask, output_dtypes, vectorize, keep_attrs, dask_gufunc_kwargs, *args)
    756     if vectorize:
    757         func = _vectorize(
    758             func, signature, output_dtypes=output_dtypes, exclude_dims=exclude_dims
    759         )
--> 761 result_data = func(*input_data)
    763 if signature.num_outputs == 1:
    764     result_data = (result_data,)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-c1295c6b-8422-4d69-982b-173176ff6a3d/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py:2286, in Variable.quantile.<locals>._wrapper(npa, **kwargs)
   2284 def _wrapper(npa, **kwargs):
   2285     # move quantile axis to end. required for apply_ufunc
-> 2286     return np.moveaxis(_quantile_func(npa, **kwargs), 0, -1)

File <__array_function__ internals>:4, in nanquantile(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: _nanquantile_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

package versions:
darts                        0.26.0
pandas                       2.0.3
numpy                        1.26.0

some data

```
----+-----+-----+-------------------+------------------+--------------------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------+-------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|  kp|  min|  max|     timestamp_hour|         avg_value|          value_diff|percentage|     moving_avg_7h|    moving_avg_30h|              5sma|              mean|stddev|z_score|    smoothed_value|             dt_iso|rain_1h|       belgium_time| Rain_cumulative_2h| Rain_cumulative_3h| Rain_cumulative_4h| Rain_cumulative_5h| Rain_cumulative_6h|dry_group|dry_hours_within_group|
+----+-----+-----+-------------------+------------------+--------------------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------+-------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|0090|150.0|848.0|2022-07-13 10:00:00|112.41159858703614|                 0.0|       0.0|112.41159858703614|112.41159858703614|112.41159858703614|112.41159858703614|   0.0|    0.0|112.41159858703614|2022-07-13 12:00:00|    0.0|2022-07-13 10:00:00|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|     NULL|                     0|
|0090|150.0|848.0|2022-07-13 11:00:00|108.46443377043072| -3.9471648166054223|       0.0|110.43801617873342|110.43801617873342|110.43801617873342|110.43801617873342|   0.0|    0.0|110.43801617873342|2022-07-13 13:00:00|    0.0|2022-07-13 11:00:00|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|     NULL|                     1|
|0090|150.0|848.0|2022-07-13 12:00:00|109.19111235245414|  0.7266785820234247|       0.0|110.02238156997366|110.02238156997366|110.02238156997366|110.02238156997366|   0.0|    0.0|110.02238156997366|2022-07-13 14:00:00|    0.0|2022-07-13 12:00:00|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|     NULL|                     2|
|0090|150.0|848.0|2022-07-13 13:00:00|112.27772883365029|  3.0866164811961454|       0.0| 110.5862183858928| 110.5862183858928| 110.5862183858928| 110.5862183858928|   0.0|    0.0| 110.5862183858928|2022-07-13 15:00:00|    0.0|2022-07-13 13:00:00|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|     NULL|                     3|
|0090|150.0|848.0|2022-07-13 14:00:00|111.91993414837381|-0.35779468527647396|       0.0|110.85296153838901|110.85296153838901|110.85296153838901|110.85296153838901|   0.0|    0.0|110.85296153838901|2022-07-13 16:00:00|    0.0|2022-07-13 14:00:00|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|                0.0|     NULL|                     4|
```

Comment: I also have this warning:

local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-b553fcb6-ede8-432e-85c2-12d4545a6916/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters/model.py:917: ConvergenceWarning: Optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals.
  warnings.warn(

Comment: Maybe the data is the issue. I ran https://unit8co.github.io/darts/#example-usage from the darts page, with darts 0.26, pandas 2.0.3, and numpy 1.24.3, without any errors.

Comment: and how do I detect the error in the data? I removed all features and left only timestamp_hour and avg_value and I still get the same error.

Comment: This is one of those try-it situations. While ChatGPT answers are not allowed on SO, it can still be very useful. I used GPT-4 on https://chat.openai.com/ with the question **How to deal with ConvergenceWarning: Optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals. warnings.warn in python statsmodels?** which gave an explanation for the warning, and a number of different ways to deal with the issue. I'd try that, to so if you can get the model to converge.

Comment: First though, make sure your datetime columns are datetime dtype, and then convert them to ordinal `df['ordinal'] = df.belgium_time.map(pd.Timestamp.toordinal)` as discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69177333/7758804)

Comment: Things from ChatGPT to try 1.  Increasing the Number of Iterations `result = model.fit(maxiter=1000)`, 2. Altering Convergence Criteria `result = model.fit(tol=1e-08)`, 3. Standardizing Variables using `from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`. Obviously these are general options.

Comment: ExponentialSmoothing.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tol'

Comment: You’ll need to look at the darts documentation to verify specific parameters